# how to convert a double into int to use it as argument in usleep?

Tags: c

I have a number like **56789098.9899** and i want to use it in usleep() which accepts only an  **unsigned integer** as argument.how to solve this problem?

**sleeptime = time_alloted - time_taken.**

Here **sleeptime** is an **unsigned int** variable.

Comment: i have to use it as usleep(sleeptime);

Comment: It's been a long time for me insofar as C is concerned, but have you tried;

    unsigned long int sleeptime;
    sleeptime=time_alloted-time_taken;

Comment: It should "just work".  What's the problem?

Comment: If something doesn't work, you should explain how. Either copy the error message or say how the actual behavior differs from what you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `usleep` accept a `usenconds_t` arguement, and `useconds_t` doesn't have to be an `unsigned int`. See `usleep` spec here.
http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/usleep.html

Second, note that the arguments must not larger than 1,000,000. And also remember to check the return value of `usleep` since it may fail.

Then just use a type cast will be fine enough.

Answer (score 0):

it should work "as is"
So the following code works fine for me:

```
#include "stdio.h"

void func(unsigned int i)
{
    printf("Going to sleep for %d\n", i);
    usleep(i);
}

int main(void)
{
   printf("hello world\n");
   unsigned int sleep;
   sleep = 56789098.9888 - 124234.45345;
   func(sleep);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: It works for you because you are assuming that the first variable is always greater than the second variable.Try making the first variable greater and then see.Also the result i obtain ie sleeptime is used inside an if condition in something like if(sleeptime > 0) then do this...Your code would break then for sure.